# On nested circles

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a problem with recursive formulas. I appreciate everyone can help me.

The problem:

We have n circles within each other. I want to achieve the value of radius of each circle such that the area bounded by two circles are the same (e.g., $|A|=|B|$). I have achieved the following equation for that:

$$R_i=\sqrt{ R_n^2 - R_{n-1}^2 + R_{i-1}^2 }$$

Known parameter:
$R_n$

In fact, I want to implement it by MATLAB.
[image]
Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean the areas of each **annulus** are equal to the area of the central circle?

Let $R_1$ be the first radius. You want

$$\pi R_2^2 - \pi R_1^2 = \pi R_1^2$$

So $R_2 = \sqrt{2}R_1$. For $n\ge 3$ you want

$$R_{n+1}^2 -  R_n^2 = R_n^2-R_{n-1}^2$$

Which gives

$$R_{n+1} = \sqrt{2R_n^2-R_{n-1}^2}$$

This recurrence relation has solution 
$$R_n = \sqrt{n}R_1$$

A proof by induction is simple. The base case is above. Then

$$R_{n+1} = \sqrt{2R_{n}^2-R_{n-1}^2} = \sqrt{2(\sqrt{n}R_1)^2 - (\sqrt{n-1}R_1)^2}$$

$$=\sqrt{[2n-(n-1)]R_1^2} = \sqrt{n+1}\cdot R_1$$